# How do I submit form data to a database and redirect someone to URL?

Tags: php

PHP Newbie here: Quick question on forms and php,

Form in Html page

```
 <form class="form" id="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"           action="submitdatabase.php">
```

I can insert data into my database successfully but how do I direct them to a certain URL as well?

If it helps, below is my PHP, needless to say it doesn't work:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("database", $con);
    $sql="INSERT INTO leads (fname, lname, address, phone, email)
          VALUES ('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[email]')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($con)
    header("Location: URLREDIRECTION.com")
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Also, `$_POST[fname]` is not valid syntax. `$_POST['fname']` is, but using it like this makes you massively vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: is your `header()` not working? and also put `;` after `mysql_close($con)`

Comment: Does this even work? You are missing a semicolon after `mysql_close()`

Comment: You have the right idea using [PHP header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). What happens when you run your script?

Comment: Are you trying to redirect the user based on the info they input or if they entered in invalid info into the form fields? I am not exactly sure what you want to do.

Comment: You have plenty of good answers now. Be sure to pick one, but even though mine was the simplest cut/paste just DO NOT choose it. There are better solutions, especially using PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP Newbie.. this should work
always use this to escape strings mysql_escape_string($var);
also `mysql_connect()` is depreciated, use `mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'database')` instead.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$fname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
$address = mysql_escape_string($_POST['address']);
$phone = mysql_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
$email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']);

mysql_select_db("database", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO leads (fname, lname, address, phone, email)
VALUES 
('$fname','$lname','$address','$phone','$email')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close($con);
header("Location: http://yoursite.com");
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer. But if you were going to re-write the majority of his script anyway why didn't you use `mysqli()`. He does have a beter answer now, but you've done the same amount of work it would take to get him all the way there, yet only brought him half way.

Answer (score 1):

This code... is... a bit of a mess and old. First things first: don't use mysql_* functions. Also you must escape your user's data [for sure](http://xkcd.com/327/). To simplify both in one, I will work with PDO. [Here you have a tutorial (just click here)](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). Also, as other stated, you also needed to close a couple of semicolons.

```
<?php
/* Create a PDO object */
$DB = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database",'root','');

/* Prepare the statement you want to do, in this case, an INSERT */
$con = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO leads (fname, lname, address, phone, email)
                     VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

/* Execute the previous statement with the corresponding values for each '?' */
$con->execute(array($_POST['fname'],
                    $_POST['lname'],
                    $_POST['address'],
                    $_POST['phone'],
                    $_POST['email']));

/* Redirect the user */
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");

?>
```

Comment: This guy is a php newbie, this might get him confused.. :):D

Comment: That's why I added the tutorial and all those comments (; I hope he understands

Comment: Sua Morales, if you don't understand something here after reading the tutorial, please don't hesitate to ask for some clarification here in the comments (:

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously this is not secure. The OP knows this and has *chosen* to do
>   things this way. If he genuinely *wants* to do things deliberately
>   wrong I have no problem with that.
>
> Anyone else reading this answer should keep in mind that this is
>   horrible practice and I have only given it as an answer because it is
>   clearly what he wanted. Do not use this.
>
> **In an actual application, you should be at the very least using `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape the `$_POST` variables from
>   user input, or (much) better yet, use MySQLi or PDO in conjunction
>   with prepared statements, to eliminate the chances of SQL injection.**

You were missing a semicolon.
Also, you changed the header line instead of leaving somewhere you were trying to redirect to there. How are we supposed to debug a script that we can't even see? Try it as posted here and see if it takes you to google. If not then there's something else going on. If it does, you typed out the `header()` function wrong but we couldn't tell, because you didn't show it to us.

Try this:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("database", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO leads (fname, lname, address, phone, email)
VALUES 
('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[email]')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close($con);
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
?>
```

Also, as a few people have pointed out already `mysql()` functions are officially depreciated. Although it should be working anyway.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! That worked. Know you just saved another 3 hours of someone's life

Comment: No, this can get your database broken and someone easily hacking into it. Please escape (sanitize) your code.

Comment: Great! You should use something to validate your code from now on when you run into problems. Because this did throw an error. Also, if you -1ed the other answer here, it is the exact same as mine just so you know.

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos We already covered that. Please put your comment under his question. Putting it under my answer makes it look like I'm the one causing the vulnerability when in fact it is his script. All I did was show him how to make it work.

Comment: Yes, I know, but since I wouldn't like -1ing every answer that doesn't mention the vulnerability, I tried to un-downvote. It was too late though.

Comment: We did mention it. Go read the second comment down on his question. You know, the place where you should have been posting this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

try this..this will work 100%

```
<?php 
  $fname=$_POST['fname'];
  $lname=$_POST['lname'];
  $phn=$_POST['phn'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $street=$_POST['street'];
  $city=$_POST['city'];
  $state=$_POST['state'];
  $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database');
  $insert= "INSERT INTO table (id,name,phone,email,street,city,state) VALUES('','$fname $lname','$phn','$email','$street','$city','$state')";
$run=mysqli_query($con,$insert);
  if($run)
  {
  header('location:https://google.com');
  }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a syntax error here:

```
mysql_close($con)
```

You need to add a semicolon:

```
mysql_close($con);
```

If your script produces any output before the `header()` statement, the redirect will not happen. Warnings, errors, and intentional output will all cause your `header()` statement to fail.

If you are redirecting to another site, consider use the 'http://' or 'https://' prefix for clarity:

```
header("Location: http://urlredirection.com");
```

If you are redirecting to your own site, just use a leading slash:

```
header("Location: /your/url.php");
```

Finally, consider updating your code to use mysqli or PDO instead of the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: I don't know why anyone voted your answer down. It's the same as mine, in fact it is more detailed. It just wasn't a cut/paste job for him. +1 from me!